# Unable to read a 'second' json file from inside a 'for' loop (Lua+Latex)

Tags: lua, json

I'm looping through a json file and displaying content in the format below:

```
Zone 1 
   Projection(Main.tex)
   Grat Table(gratsection.tex)
Zone 2
   Projection (Main.tex)
   Grat table (gratsection.tex)
```

Main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Font Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[nohead,paperheight=11.0in,paperwidth=8.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

%%%% Font %%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%%%% dynamic table package %%%%%
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}% Set the separator between the columns.
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%% Section %%%%%%

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 16pt


\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\bfseries}X|X}
\catcode10=9\

\begin{luacode*}
local json = require("json")
local file = io.open("data.json")
tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
file:close()

for ii,jj in ipairs(tab["Zones"]) do  
 
   %% PROJECTION
            tex.sprint(
                [[\begin{table}[ht!]
                \centering
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{}}
                \hline]])
                for w, v in ipairs(jj.Projection.Header) do
                    tex.sprint(
                    [[\textbf]],
                    v.key, [[& ]],
                    v.val, [[\\]],
                    [[\hhline{--}]])
                end  
            tex.sprint(
                [[
                \end{tabularx}
                \end{table}]])
  %%GRAT SECTION  
   tex.sprint([[\input{gratsection}]])
   
end
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

if '\input{gratsection.tex}' is called outside the 'for' loop, my MWE shows Projection information twice( 2 objects in the Zone array) and the Grat table once:
[image]

but I'm unable to show the Grat table from the section file under each Projection zone. Grat table ( from gratsection.tex) doesnt show up when inside the 'FOR' loop. Code is caught in a infinite loop and doesnt compile but dont see any error. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

gratsection.tex

```
\section*{ SECTION 2(GRAT)}
\newcolumntype{L}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\bfseries}X|X}
\catcode10=9\


\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand*{\tabularx}{\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}\oldtabularx}


\begin{luacode*}
local json = require("json")
local file = io.open("graticule_table.json")
tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
file:close()

tex.sprint(
    [[\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{}}
    \hline]])
    for k, v in ipairs(tab["GratTable"]) do
        tex.sprint(
        [[\textbf]],
        v.LATDEG, [[& ]],
        v.LATMIN, [[\\]],
        [[\hhline{--}]])
    end  
tex.sprint(
    [[
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}]])

\end{luacode*}
```

data.json

```
{
    "Zones":[
        {
          "name":"Zone 1",
          "Projection": {
            "Zone": "29",
            "Header": [
              {
                "key": "MAP NAME",
                "val": "XX"
              },
              {
                "key": "PROJECTION",
                "val": "YY"
              }
            ]
          },
          "Grat": {
            "Header": [
              {
                "key": "SHEET NAME",
                "val": "AA"
              },
              {
                "key": "PROJECTION",
                "val": "BB"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name":"Zone 2",
          "Projection": {
            "Zone": "30",
            "Header": [
              {
                "key": "MAP NAME",
                "val": "AA"
              },
              {
                "key": "PROJECTION",
                "val": "BB"
              }
            ]
                     },
          "Grat": {
            "Header": [
              {
                "key": "SHEET NAME",
                "val": "XX"
              },
              {
                "key": "PROJECTION",
                "val": "YY"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
   ]
}
```

graticule_table.json ( this isa huge file need to keep it seperate)

```
{
     "GratTable": [
            {
                "LATDEG": "1",
                "LATMIN": "30"
            },
            {
                "LATDEG": "2",
                "LATMIN": "45"
               
            }
            ]
}
```

and json.lua file that parses the JSON is from http://regex.info/blog/lua/json

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to typeset some json-arrays, i.e. display them "in-print", or do you want to execute "them"? Whatever "execution" should mean in this context ... Please edit your question and clarify your final goal, best in a beginning one-sentence statement. Thanks.

Comment: please provide an example in a form that can be used to see the errro, as the error is in section 1 you can minimise it by dropping section2 (and making section1 part of teh main file to make it easier to set up the test document) also provide a small example json file as text not an image (as small as possible to show the problem)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited my example and also attached json file as text

Comment: @MS-SPO I want to read the objects from the json file and display them in a table. I'm using a for loop to access the array of json objects...this works in Main.tex file but my section file is unaware of this 'for' loop and hence doesnt show the table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I took ur advice and combined all sections in main.tex but having issue including one last section ( that reads a different json file) inside a for loop in main.tex